# Conditional Tagging based on a criteria

Tags: tableau-api

Here's how my data looks ike

```
customer    category
customer 1  A
customer 1  B
customer 1  null
customer 2  A
customer 2  NULL
customer 3  B
customer 3  C
customer 4  A
customer 4  B
```

What I'd like to do is this.

If any of the customers have a mandatory category A and also any other category( be it B, C or D) with it, then tag this as 1 else 0.

for e.g customer 1 has A as well as B then it would be 1, but customer 2 has only A and a null so it would be 0.

In short, I want to see which of my customers has categories other than A. But category A has to be one of them. Nulls don't count.
Any idea what would be the best approach to this. Here's how I'd like to transform this table to.

```
customer    Tag
customer 1  1
customer 2  0
customer 3  0
customer 4  1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following expression is true when there is at least one record with category A  and at least one record with a category other than A: `max([category]=“A”) and max([category]<>“A”)`

For example, if you put customer on rows and the above calc on Text/Label, you’ll see your result.

This works because Tableau treats True as greater than False, So Max(condition) is true if and only if condition is satisfied by at least one data record.